# confidence interval for a bounded distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given 1000 observations that come from a distribution that is bounded between 0 and 1. How do you calculate correct 95% Confidence intervals for the MEAN when dealing with a bounded distribution?

## R code

```
set.seed(10)
data =runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1)
mean(data)
mean(data)+1.96*sd(data)/sqrt(length(data)) #usual CIs
mean(data)-1.96*sd(data)/sqrt(length(data)) #usual CIs
```

Are there any references on how to calculate 95% CIs for bounded distributions?

Comment: You should clearly mention what kind of confidence interval you want, e.g., CI for mean, median, quantile....

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Central Limit Theorem approximation for the distribution of the mean, justified by a finite variance of the original distribution (which is $\frac{1}{12}$ in this case) and a large sample size (which is $1000$ here)

So unless your original random variable has particularly extreme features (it does not in this case), you do not need to worry much about whether the original random variable has bounded or unbounded support

Your example code gives a sample mean of about $0.505$ and a confidence interval of about $[0.487, 0.523]$, which contains the true population mean of $0.5$.  Using different seeds and your $1.96$ multiple, you would expect about $95\%$ of examples of confidence intervals to contain the true population mean.  I think that for example seeds of 28, 44, 100, 140, 141, 147, 153, 154, or 160 would not

Comment: So you are making use of the CLT but why is there a need for confidence intervals using bootstrpping or here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDF-based_nonparametric_confidence_interval when the distribution is bounded. Why wouldn't everyone just use CLT?  So you are saying the standard error is accurate? Imagine you get a sd of .22 with 1000 observations and a mean of .5 the upper 95% confidence level is  .513.  Seem very low no? If you look at a histogram with sd=.22 and mean of .5 saying 95% is .513 seems odd.

Comment: Your example code gives a sample mean of about $0.505$ and a confidence interval of about $[0.487, 0.523]$, which contains the true population mean of $0.5$.  Using different seeds, you would expect $95\%$ of examples of confidence intervals to contain the true population mean.